# Multiple column query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with master information, which is being pulled into several other sheets based on information within any given row. For instance, the status in column C for Sub Set 1, 2, and 3, so:

```
=query('Master Info'!A:G, "select * where C = 'A' order by A")
```

worked well, but then for Sub Set 4, we are trying to to get any row which has 'PM=' in any cell (of any column), which became a very repetitive query. In the sample it is:

```
=query('Master Info'!A:I, "select * where A starts with 'PM=' or B starts with 'PM=' or C starts with 'PM=' or D starts with 'PM=' or E starts with 'PM=' or F starts with 'PM=' or G starts with 'PM=' or H starts with 'PM=' or I starts with 'PM=' order by A")
```

In the actual sheet, there are 35 rows, so the query is quite a bit longer.

I am wondering if there is a way to define the where as a range, such as:

```
=query('Master Info'!A:I, "select * where A:I starts with 'PM=' order by A")
```

However that code does not function properly, and provides a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: @pnuts I believe that would work if I understand you correctly. Are you saying setting a column to display a flag if a cell in that row starts with 'PM=' and then having the sheet query the page for any rows that have the flag? How would that flag column be set?

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like:

```
=--ISNUMBER(match("PM*",B1:J1,0))
```

to set a flag in say A1 and copy down to suit.